# Does the Apple Remote work on Windows 7 64bit?

Tags: windows-7, 64-bit, boot-camp

Has anyone succesfully used the Apple Remote under Windows 7 64bit?

It doesn't work on my machine (I'm still running Windows 7 RC).

I've installed the Boot Camp Services 2.1.0, and no... the remote is not disabled in the Boot Camp Control Panel.

Answer (score 3):

with the apple remote, i can launch itunes when i press menu.  the apple remote controls itunes as well as windows media player if media player is open.  it also controls VLC media player, i didnt have to do anything differently.

Answer (score 2):

I successfully used the Apple Remote on Windows 7 Pro 64bit using Bootcamp. It can at least control the volume, but not do much more I fear.

However, I noticed that the sound would sometimes just go up or down with no apparent reason. Switching the Apple Remote off on Bootcamp solved the issue. Since I didn't quite need it when running Windows I didn't try to have a deeper look. I have no idea whether it comes from the driver or from the actual remote/receiver but since I have no problem when running Mac OS, I more suspect the driver.

Answer (score 1):

I don't have any experience with the Apple and you don't say what you're using it for.

I've had to install [EventGhost](http://www.eventghost.org/) to get my MCE remote working properly outside of mce. Maybe you need to try it out or possibly go with IR Server suite (don't have a download link handy)